# Grabbing all QPushButton in a PyQt Python ui File

Tags: python, pyqt, loops, qpushbutton

I created a UI File using Qt Designer with lots of QPushButtons, and then I converted it into a python file using pyuic4.

I want to add all the QPushButtons to a QButtonGroup.

How do I iterate or grab all my QPushButtons to add in to a QButtonGroup from my UI Python file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Qt Designer, put all your buttons inside a container widget.

You can then use [findChildren](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#findChildren) to iterate over all the child buttons. So if `self.buttonBox` was your container widget, then you could do something like:

```
self.buttonGroup = QtGui.QButtonGroup(self)
for button in self.buttonBox.findChildren(QtGui.QAbstractButton):
    self.buttonGroup.addButton(button)
```